# UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcprov in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, shared-libraries

I have setup soft Eracom Safenet HSM in Linux.

I am facing a problem regarding Safenet Eracom HSM, when ever I request for token initialization got this error

**UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcprov in java.library.path**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I just added below path in .bashrc file for corresponding user.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/PTK/lib
```

Then restarted the terminal after that it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Add **jcprov** containing directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/path/of/Containing/Directory
```